# Why are jQuery mouseenter events triggered in an unspecified order?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-handling, mouseenter

I have 3 divs containing each other like a [Matryoshka doll](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matryoshka_doll).

[image]

For all divs, I've a function bound the mousenter event. Now moving the mouse ***slowly*** from the bottom, and entering into layer three will result in the following events:

1. Mouseenter layer one
2. Mouseenter layer two
3. Mouseenter layer three

Which is perfect, and the expected result, as you need to enter layer one first, in order to enter layer two, etc.

However if I do the same with a ***quick*** mouse movement, the order will be unspecified, for example:

1. Mouseenter layer two
2. Mouseenter layer one
3. Mouseenter layer three

Which doesn't make too much sense to me - how can your mouse enter layer two *before* entering layer one?

Anyway, the question is: is there any way to force jQuery or javascript in general to fire these events in their natural order? If no, can you suggest me a workaround, like somehow post sorting the events from my event handler function, and postponing those that were prematurely called?

Test code is posted at http://jsbin.com/ibepu6/4/

Comment: curious - using latest Firefox and Chrome on a modest spec PC (by today's standards) I can't replicate your result no matter how fast I move the mouse.

Comment: @Alnitak: I'm using FF 3.6.16 on a Core2Duo Vista notebook. I can reproduce this behavior any time. Try to add more layers and smaller paddings to the stacked divs. Can you reproduce it then?

Comment: @Alnitak: http://jsbin.com/ibepu6/14 has smaller paddings and 5 layers. Test it please.

Comment: i think it is bubble problem , is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally mouseenter and mouseleave events are microsoft based events, jquery make them useable in all browsers using other function to create this effect... First have a loook at and test the demo in [jquery event page](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/). I do not check the jquery source, but there is two diffrent event ordering mechanism in javascript as far as i know... Event capturing and event bubbling...

[This document](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html)  is not new, but it describes the basics whish you need.  [This is an older document](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html) about mouse events and how do they executed...

So check jquery source and see how mouseenter and mouseleave works. As i said before, it is not the basic function that only runs on IE, but a simulation that acts just like mouseenter and mouseleave events by using other javascript functions... Thats how jquery enebles these two Microsoft event available to all browsers...

Comment: The quirksmode.org link is very useful, I certainly learned a lot from that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I edited your code in Jsbin to post sort the events that are triggered. I am not sure if it is useful at all for your case but here is the code [Edited Jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ibepu6/13)

Comment: omerkirk: That is cool but you're relying on the divs' ids for sorting. I had these specific ids for demo purposes only, a very simplified example of the real world situation I'm facing. What I'd need is a) sort the events based on dom hierarchy, b) somehow group the events (events only belong together if they happen within a delta timeframe)

Comment: I guessed it wouldn't be useful :) The problem is the mouseenter event does not exist. It is a custom event defined by jquery so it performs quite a bit of operations in the background, even if you have a single div if you move the mouse fast enough it doesn't even trigger this event.

Answer (score -1):

problem is:

you can not in any case take your mouse directly to third layer as it is inside second which is inside first. there is visible parts of second and first layer.

No matter how fast you move your mouse, it will still trigger first or second before the third. There is no obvious solution to this, visible second and first layer parts mouse over will always trigger second and first mouse over before the third. If you move very fast this order can be changed but it can not be consistent.

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood my question. My problem is not that all three events will be fired. That is the expected behavior and a Good Thing. My problem is that given fast enough mouse movements, the order of these events will be mixed up. I'd need consistent order, how to achieve that?